# If Ratio Test for an alternating series is Divergent, Must I run the Alternating series test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

If I conduct the ratio test for a series that is alternating in sign, and find that $\lim$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ is $ >1$, is it mathematically correct to say that the entire series (including the alternating piece) is divergent?  Or, must I conduct the alternating series convergence test?

Comment: What is "the entire series" and "the alternating piece"?

Comment: $(-1)^n$ or $(-1)^(n+1)$ is the alternating piece and $5^n/n^6$ is non-alternating piece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ratio test for the absolute values of the terms gives a limit $>1$, the terms cannot go to zero and therefore the original series diverges by the Divergence Test.

Comment: This now makes sense.  So, I don't need to also conduct the Alternating series test?  That test wouldn't tell me divergence anyway, only if it converged.  So, I'm done, right?

Comment: Yes you are. To test your understanding, apply your argument to the example $\sum_n (1)^n 3^n/n$ where it should give the same result.

Comment: Makes complete sense now.  Do I have to wait 2 days to select the "accept this answer" check mark?